# Table of contents in two column, without multicol

Tags: table-of-contents, two-column

Is there any way to make table of contents in two column **without using multicol**?

I added `twocolumn` in the document class, but the table of contents is still one column.

All solutions I found are using muitlcol.

However, using `multicol` in twocolumn mode gives me warning:

```
Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option on input line 150.
```

So, I don't want to use `multicol`. Is there any way to make table of contents in two column **without using `multicol`**?

EDIT:
I am using `book` class

Comment: But is  the body of your document in two columns, or single column?

Comment: the `\tableofcontents` command restores for `book` class to one column,

Comment: @Bernard the body is two column

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the problem is come from the book class? how to overcome this problem if I want to use book class?

Comment: you can try `{\let\onecolumn\relax\tableofcontents}`

Comment: @touhami: Too easy ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `\tableofcontents` command from the standard `book.cls` checks whether `twocolumn` mode has been activated, uses `onecolumn` and sets a flag in order to restore to `twocolumn` after that.

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

I decided to use a new command, say `\twocolumntoc` which does not check.
It is, of course, possible to put the `twocolumn` command into the new macro and the restoration with `\onecolumn` at the end of the command.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\twocolumntoc

\onecolumn

\foreach \x in {1,...,50}{%
\chapter{Chap \x}
\section{Foo section}
\subsection{Foo subsec}
\subsubsection{Foo subsecsec}
}
\end{document}
```

The `pgffor` package is only for quick generation of content in here.

Comment: I vote now your post. But you vote mine post?

Comment: @Sebastiano ... done for three, I can't vote for more in a short period

Comment: problem solved,thanks a lot. I edited `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` to `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`, because the previous one includes all paragraph title in the toc, and generates 18 errors... lol

Comment: @fairytale: Well, you did not post an example, so I used 4 instead of 2 ;-). If the problem is solve, accept the answer please

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thus I have undestood as I must vote. Now I have vote for seven users. Thankssssssssssssss.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the system requires me to wait for 1 minute, please wait

Comment: @samcarter: That's true but not the right place to discuss it *here* ;-)