# How to set TOC title above its content when that is in two columns?

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol

As the title says I would like to have the title („Contents") appear above both columns as this picture suggests:[image: Desired editing for TOC]

I.e. the items within the table of contents should start at the same level in them both. Currently the title is considered as part of the first column (that is the issue). The creation I am following seems quite simple – using multicols –, so I might need guidance for a completely new direction replacing that. Below you can find my code:

```
\documentclass[7pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{8pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
 \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}



\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}


\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353866/table-of-contents-in-two-column-without-multicol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `multicol`, you can enter two-column mode, do the ToC, and return to one-column mode.

Using the answer [ToC in two column without multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353870/161015)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[7pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{8pt}


%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353870/161015
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \twocolumn
    \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
        \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \onecolumn
    }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
\twocolumntoc % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
    

\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}

\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
\chapter{Asdf}
    
\end{document}
```

If you want a balanced columns, you can now use the `multicol` package with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
        \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \@starttoc{toc}%
    \end{multicols}
    \onecolumn
    }
\makeatother
```

to get

[image: b]

Comment: On another note this seems to turn off ```\cftbeforetoctitleskip```.
Do you know how may I modify the spacing with this new structure?

Comment: @Marton This site works best with one question at the time, to help other readers. Please add another question with some code that shows the problem.