# How to set TOC title above its content when using multicols and tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, multicol, tocloft

**Background:** Hello there. I read this [Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639405/how-to-set-toc-title-above-its-content-when-that-is-in-two-columns), which I thought would answer my question, but I am still confused (surely due to my newness to LaTeX). I have a two-column table of contents that uses multicols and tocloft. The second/right column of toc entries starts on the same line (aka, in the same vertical orientation on the page) as the left-aligned title of the toc, which starts the left column.

**Difficulty:** I would like the title of the toc to appear above all the entries.

**Original code:**

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{This is my report}
\author{H.S.}
\date{May, 2023}
\begin{document}

\hypersetup{linktoc=all,
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=blue}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\LARGE\aftergroup \LARGE} % credit to @user691586
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{0pt} %control left margin of entry lines 2+
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{} %new % Eliminate tocloft's auto section numbers
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus 1fil} %set right margin for toc
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{
  \fontsize{35pt}{35pt}\selectfont
  \bfseries}
\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\end{hyphenrules}

\clearpage
\section{Section One Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Two Title, Long Enough for Multiple Lines}
\clearpage
\section{Section Three Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Four Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Five Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Six Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Seven Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Eight Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Nine Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Ten Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Eleven Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Twelve Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Thirteen Title, surely enough to hit two columns}

\end{document}
```

**First attempt at a fix:** I tried to incorporate the solution @Simon Dispa suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639405/how-to-set-toc-title-above-its-content-when-that-is-in-two-columns), but I clearly misunderstood how to include that solution because the toc page ended up being missing altogether:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{This is my report}
\author{H.S.}
\date{May, 2023}
\begin{document}

\hypersetup{linktoc=all,
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=blue}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{
    \section*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
      \@starttoc{toc}%
  \end{multicols}
  \onecolumn
  }
\makeatother

\clearpage
\section{Section One Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Two Title, Long Enough for Multiple Lines}
\clearpage
\section{Section Three Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Four Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Five Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Six Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Seven Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Eight Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Nine Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Ten Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Eleven Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Twelve Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Thirteen Title, surely enough to hit two columns}

\end{document}
```

**Possible fix I hope to do better than:** I think I could just use \begingroup ... \endgroup twice to achieve: (1) a group that just contains text displaying the toc title; and then beneath that, (2) a group with the toc code, where the title gets suppressed with \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}. I'm guessing that would work, but based on the existence of @Simon Dispa's response to @Marton [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639405/how-to-set-toc-title-above-its-content-when-that-is-in-two-columns), it feels like there ought to be a cleaner answer than that. But maybe not, and that's my best answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: I added a solution which is roughly the kind of thing you envisioned at end of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on basis of OP original efforts; but inserting `\tableofcontents` inside the `multicols` is not obvious to rescue.  Ideally, it would be better to simply look at LaTeX source code, not use `tocloft` at all, and code oneself the desired insertion of the multicols, and all various desired special things such as choice of font etc... one discovers the hooks added by `tocloft` are not the ideal means as one can not control if they are hardcoded to expand in a group for example.  In the end rather than watching a log trace of the executed TeX expansion with `latex+ tocloft` better to use `latex` plus `article` (or whatever) class only, but I will here continue the `latex+article+tocloft+multicols+whatever new package...`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\hypersetup{linktoc=all,
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=blue}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}% This is the default

% Toc configutation via tocloft interface.  Which is not best of tools
% for us here.
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\LARGE\aftergroup \LARGE} % credit to @user691586

% Eliminate tocloft's auto section numbers
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{0pt} %control left margin of entry lines 2+
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{} %new

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{% <- avoid extra space token
  \fontsize{35pt}{35pt}\selectfont
  \bfseries}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus 1fil} %set right margin for toc
% must get rid to some extent of tocloft handling the TOC heading
% we did not correct various potential vertical space, not that importnat
  \let\@cftmaketoctitle\@empty
\makeatother


\title{This is my report}
\author{H.S.}
\date{May, 2023}


\begin{document}

\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}% configure multicols
% attenton that [{...}] would have multicols anyhow remove the braces
% so it should be [{{...}}] but anyhow we issue \normalfont to reset
% the font size and series; \noindent avoids indentation
\begin{multicols}{2}[\noindent\cfttoctitlefont\contentsname\normalfont]
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\end{hyphenrules}

\clearpage
\section{Section One Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Two Title, Long Enough for Multiple Lines}
\clearpage
\section{Section Three Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Four Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Five Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Six Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Seven Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Eight Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Nine Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Ten Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Eleven Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Twelve Title}
\clearpage
\section{Section Thirteen Title, surely enough to hit two columns}

\end{document}
```

[image: a table of contents with tocloft and multicols]

I am not sure why hyphenation should be suppressed but I kep this.

I would have rather used some `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e`.

Comment: Oh wow! @user691586, that's super impressive. Thank you so much! This solution worked a treat. I also appreciate your comments about why tocloft isn't the best solution here. It's very tempting as a newbie to just use these packages because they help a person do customizations quickly without having to learn more nuanced latex code, but... sounds like that's a recipe for getting stuck. Appreciate the lesson. Have a great day!

*PS: the hyphenation suppression relates to some visual design concerns that are not visible in the sample doc. Normally I'd agree with you!